# doc/docx to postscript/ps

Tags: c#, pdf

I want to convert a doc/docx file to postscript by C# without using Word save to file since Word saved a big ps file. 
Also, I want to know if there is a way to optimize a PDF by C#.
can I do that?

Comment: Standard reply: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Simple:  Install any Postscript printer driver, set its port to FILE: and then print the document to that printer.  Doing it from C# means you'll have to know how to print a Word file, but the word format (at least .doc) is mostly just RTF so shouldn't be too difficult.  As for optimizing PDF, sure, you can do that from C#, but I don't know what you mean by "optimize."

Comment: I already setup the printer and printed to Prn from word.  However, it needs to open 
W the PRN file size is also larger than another one who did the same PS by just writing PS from program.  each file in PRN is around 150k and if i have 1000 files it becomes 150M.  But another one write the same result as PS just 30k only.

Comment: I have the C# to print the Word to PRN already but it needs to open Word each time. I have over 1000 files so Word need to open/print/close 1000 times. Can C# convert it to PS without using Word?
Also, using Word to print PRN result my PRN in 150k for each. I have 1000 files, it becomes 150MB and can't be sent to Printing Company,where they said others write the PS 30k@.
Moreover, I used iText to convert it to PDF but the file is 30M but if I use Acrobat Distiller to convert the PRN to PDF, it becomes 5M only. Acrobat has a optimize function to minimize the PDF. How can I optimize a PDF?

Answer (score 0):

did you find anyway so you can convert doc/docx to ps?I have the same problem.
I know that it's too late to help you, but you can use ghostscript for optimizing pdf

```
        int ExitCode;
        ProcessStartInfo ProcessInfo;
        Process Process;

        ProcessInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("gswin64.exe", "-dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=C:\\26178DATA\\LowResOutput.pdf -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 C:\\26178DATA\\Holding.pdf");
        ProcessInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        ProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        ProcessInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

        Process = Process.Start(ProcessInfo);
        Process.WaitForExit();
        ExitCode = Process.ExitCode;
        Process.Close();
```